# python, sqlite3 and two values

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

How to take two values into sqlite3 ?

```
v1 = '2011.11.10'
v2 = 10

vv1=(v1,)
vv2=(v2,)


conn = sqlite3.connect('date.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute(" UPDATE archive SET date=? WHERE Id=? ", (vv1,vv2) ) # (vv1,vv2) this is not work, how?
conn.commit()
```

I know, that probably a simple , but can't find anything on net. Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
v1 = '2011.11.10'
v2 = 10
...
c.execute(" UPDATE archive SET date=? WHERE Id=? ", (v1,v2) )
```

For `cursor.execute`, pass a sequence of values, not a sequence of sequence of values.

For `cursor.executemany`, in contrast, you *would* want to pass a sequence of sequences.